# Check if all dropdowns are empty or not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `select` elements:

```
            <select id="first">
                <option></option>
                <option value="a">a</option>
                <option value="b">b</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
            </select>
            <select id="second">
                <option></option>
                <option value="d">d</option>
                <option value="e">e</option>
                <option value="f">f</option>
            </select>
            <select id="three">
                <option></option>
                <option value="g">g</option>
                <option value="h">h</option>
                <option value="i"></option>
            </select>
```

All three of them must either be empty (first option), or have a value.

So `<option></option> <option></option> <option></option>` is ok

but not `<option value="a">a</option> <option></option> <option></option>` kinda thing.

I've tried this, but it isn't working as it doesn't allow all three to be empty and quits on the first case

```
if($("#first").val() === "" || $("#second").val() === "" || $("#third").val() === ""){
    return false;
}
```

Any help? I would like to do this as short/nice looking as possible

Comment: have you added jquery.validate() ? for validation purpose ?

Comment: if yes! you just need to use `required:true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could

```
var $selects = $('#first, #second, #three'),
    $selected = $selects.filter(function () {
        return this.value != ''
    });
if ($selected.length != 0 && $selected.length != $selects.length) {
    return false;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dxgmaLg7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = $("#first").val();
var second = $("#first").val();
var three = $("#first").val();
var isValid = false;

if((first.length>0 && second.length>0 && three.length>0) || (first.length==0 && second.length>== && three.length==0)){
    isValid = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($("#first").find('option').length <=1 || $("#second").find('option').length <=1 || $("#third").find('option').length <=1){
return false;
}
```